# Facebook Plugin

Tags: facebook

Is there any plugin or way to post on my facebook wall directly from my website?

(There are plugins available for WordPress. But mine is not a blog site).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook has a full REST api, so you should be able to use it from any language.  If you are using PHP you could look at what the wordpress plugin is doing and then replicate that for your page.  Otherwise you probably should look at the SDK information for facebooks api processes and then just call them however you need from your site.

Answer (score 0):

There's a comments widget.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools.php?connect_wizard&wizard=comments